# Android Studio Swictch-case Instance not working properly

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have been making an app which has a navigation drawer, but that navigation drawer isn't working with the switch case I've made. The id's are right.

For starters here's the shortened version of my code:

**Here's my java class:**

```
public class Image extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

        //DRAWER LAYOUT
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
            { switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case(R.id.nav_account): Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity);
                case(R.id.nav_exercises): Intent accountActivity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Video.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity1);
                case(R.id.nav_tips): Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Image.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity2);
            }
                return true;
            } );

        //Navigation Drawer



}



    //FOR NAVIGATION DRAWER


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    //Navigation Drawer End


}
```

**Here are the XML's:**

**navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Account" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="Settings"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_exercises"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_accessibility_black_24dp"
        android:title="Exercises"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_tips"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_face_black_24dp"
        android:title="Tips"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_scheduler"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_date_range_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Schedule"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_info"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
        android:title="Info"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_input_black_24dp"
        android:title="Logout"/>

</menu>
```

**Here's where I apply the drawer:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.Welcome.Video"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="259dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="videoplay"
        android:text="Play" />
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
    >


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What happens is when the navigation drawer, I click `nav_exercises` case but what shows is the view of the supposed to be  for the `nav_tips`. I click back and then it goes to the exercises part. The TIPS is working just as it is.

But the EXERCISES part, it shows the TIPS view and then when you press "back" it goes to the right place. In other words it's somehow overlapping with the other view.

What did I do wrong? I'm sure the class and ID's are in the right places, I've checked for an hour really.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Should always refer to the [official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) & other online documentation before searching/asking elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `break;` otherwise every case will be executed

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId())
{
    case(R.id.nav_account): Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class);
        startActivity(accountActivity);
        break;
        //^^^
    case(R.id.nav_exercises): Intent accountActivity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Video.class);
        startActivity(accountActivity1);
        break;
        //^^^
    case(R.id.nav_tips): Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Image.class);
        startActivity(accountActivity2);
        break;// not needed at last but good practice
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the switch case

like

```
  switch (request.getMethod()) {
            case Method.GET:
                ...
                break;
            case Method.DELETE:
                ...    
                break;
            case Method.POST:
                ...
                break;
            case Method.PUT:
                ...
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown method type.");
        }
```